# rsync for sharing files across nodes in application cluster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cluster-computing, rsync, nfs

I've a Rails application that runs on multiple load-balanced nodes.  One of its functions is allowing users to upload content.  That content needs to be visible fairly quickly, if not immediately, to all nodes.

Currently each node mounts a directory from an NFS server and reads/writes uploaded content to that shared location.

If possible, I'd like to move away from this solution and instead store content locally (on each node) and periodically sync with an rsync server in order to keep all nodes in sync.

Is this reasonable?  How would rsync behave if a certain file were modified on multiple nodes at approximately same time?  Would the changes be serialized on the "server" with no potential for corruption (i.e. each change only partially applied resulting in an corrupted file)?

I considered using some other shared resource (database, redis, etc.) but given how this content is used it's highly desirable for it to exist in "raw" form on the filesystem.

Comment: What about using something like AWS or some other cloud storage instead or would it be cost prohibitive?

Comment: Technically that would work, but it would necessitate updating the (~300) mobile apps that use this Rails server and I'm not in a position to make that happen.  If we had it to do over again then I'd advocate hosting this stuff in the cloud.  C'est la vie.

Comment: I could maybe designate one machine as the "content server" and then create a rule on our load balancer to send all requests that match a certain URL pattern to that machine.  Then, when content is uploaded, the nodes in the cluster would send it to that single "content server".  That's actually not at terrible idea.